# How can I put "sub-classes" in a class

Tags: c#

I´m coming from VB and I´m total new to C. I have 2 Classes:

```
public class Location {
  public decimal lat {get;set;}
  public decimal lon {get;set;}
}
public class credentials {
  public string username {get;set;}
  public string passwordhash {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to use these 2 classes within some other classes in a way, that the new class looks like this:

```
public class something1 {
  public string property1 {get;set;}
  public string property2 {get;set;}
  // next 2 lines should be avoided -> class "Location"
  public decimal lat {get;set;}
  public decimal lon {get;set;}
  // next 2 lines should be avoided -> class "credentials"
  public string username {get;set;}
  public string passwordhash {get;set;}
}
```

How can I realize this? I´m not familiar with all the OO-stuff.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy:

```
public class something1 {
  public string property1 {get;set;}
  public string property2 {get;set;}
  public Location property3  {get;set;}
  public credentials property4 {get;set}
}
```

NOTE:

1. This is composition the classes are not called "sub-classes" they are just other classes - in exactly the same way `string` is another class.
2. I am assuming your classes are in the same namespace, otherwise you would need add a `using MyOtherNamespace` above the class definitions in the file.

To access these you do the same as accessing any other property on an instance of `something1`, e.g.

```
something1 mySomething1 = new Something1();
mySomething1.Location = new Location();
string cred = mySomething1.credentials.ToString(); // oops you may get a null ref because nothing has been assigned to mySomething1.credentials yet so it will be `null`;
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove `username` and `passwordhash`, too

Comment: If I make it like this, accessing lon must be: something1.Location.lon, right? But I Need something.lon, because I get serialized json data and want to store it in the object.